# Particles (hair) size and random size in blender 2.79a not available in advanced

Tags: particles, hair

After many years on C4D, I started to learn Blender and follow the beginner tutorial series of Andrew Price.

On part 7 about particles, he changes the size and the random size of the particles group that needed to create sprinkles on a donut.
He uses this menu, as shown in the doc [blender doc](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/particles/emitter/physics/newtonian.html)

But for me, in Blender 2.79a the size / random size is available in the "render" tab while *Advanced* is unchecked. When *Advanced* is checked it disappears from the render tab and I can't find it anymore.

So if I want to tweak and randomize my particles, I have to check/uncheck.

Is it normal or am I missing a thing on 2.79 ?

[image: picture from his tutorial]

edit : confirmed that in *Advanced* those settings are available in Blender 2.79.

Answer (score 2):

It is normal and documented here:

https://lists.blender.org/pipermail/bf-blender-cvs/2018-January/103452.html